# How to switch between Rust toolchains?

Tags: rust, rustup

`rustup help toolchain` lists the following sub-commands

```
SUBCOMMANDS:
    list         List installed toolchains
    install      Install or update a given toolchain
    uninstall    Uninstall a toolchain
    link         Create a custom toolchain by symlinking to a directory
    help         Prints this message or the help of the given subcommand(s)
```

I have the following toolchains installed

```
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-2019-09-05-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
master
```

I was trying to solve an issue for rust-clippy so I had to install the master toolchain. Even though stable is set as my default toolchain, my current toolchain is master and I would like to switch back to stable. How do I do it without uninstalling the master toolchain?

Is there no switch subcommand?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no "current" toolchain unless you set environment variables. You're either running it like `cargo +nightly clippy` or you're using the default toolchain.

Comment: @PitaJ, running `rustup default` will tell you the default toolchain cargo will use by default unless specified otherwise in a `.toml` config file.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Of course the `rustup default stable` command works well, but the easiest way is to keep a `rust-toolchain` file inside your project root folder. Similar to how you'd keep a `.nvm` file for a Node.js project.

Please note that if you use `rust-toolchain.toml` instead of just `rust-toolchain` you will need to add needed sections similar to JSON [ref](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#the-toolchain-file) and hence I prefer just the simple `rust-toolchain` file which doesn't need any sections similar to Node.js's `.nvm` file.

> Cargo is not concerned with versioning for toolchains, +nightly is handled by a rustup wrapper; hence a separate file.

**rust-toolchain**

```
nightly
```

[image: screenshot of IDE with rust-toolchain file]

or

```
stable
```

Please note you could even add toml like sections to `rust-toolchain` file.

exmaple: `./rust-toolchain`

```
[toolchain]
channel = "1.72.0"
components = [ "rustfmt", "clippy" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
```

Comment: This seems like the more conventional/robust approach so upvoted.

Comment: Why does this setting go in a weird extra file I've never heard of instead of the Cargo.toml?

Comment: @mako because `cargo` isn't concerned at all with Rust version managment. (`+nightly` is handled by a `rustup` wrapper)

Answer (score 67):

To toggle between nightly and stable configurations in your repo use:

```
rustup override set nightly
```

or:

```
rustup override set stable
```

Answer (score 64):

Use `rustup default <toolchain>` to change the default toolchain. You can use the full name (e.g. `rustup default stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`) or a short alias (e.g. `rustup default stable`).

rustup also has methods to override the default in a more scoped manner. See [Overrides](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) in the rustup book.

Comment: What if I just want to use switch toolchains temporarily, e.g. also to use `cargo clippy`, when my default toolchain is nightly?

Comment: I found the answer: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup#toolchain-override-shorthand. In the above scenario, I can do `cargo +stable clippy`

Comment: Is there any minimal toolchain? I'm only interested in running a few commands such as `cargo generate-lockfile` and `cargo tree`

Answer (score 12):

`rustup default stable` should work. This will set `stable` as the default toolchain globally.

To set `stable` as the default toolchain for just one directory/ project, use `rustup override set stable` command instead. To unset it, use `rustup override unset`.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into an issue where I thought I set the default using `rustup default {VERSION}` but it kept loading a specific version of rust that was not what I added.

I found that my repo had a file:
`rust-toolchain.toml` that was overriding the version.
I renamed the file and it corrected to the right version of rustc