# Why is my rustup rust-toolchain file not overriding the default?

Tags: rust, toolchain, nightly-build, rustup

I want to use the Rust "nightly" build to work with Arrow and Datafusion. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226545/how-to-switch-between-rust-toolchains) and the rustup [book](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html?highlight=rust-toolchain#the-toolchain-file) I should be able to put a rust-toolchain file in the home directory of the project containing just the word "nightly" and that should make it the default build for that project. However, this isn't working.

Any suggestions of what I am missing?

When I check the default, I see that it is using the "stable" build.

```
(base) Apples-MBP:data_fusion_tutorial Daniel$ rustup default
stable-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
```

Here is what my project directory looks like:

```
(base) Apples-MBP:data_fusion_tutorial Daniel$ ls -a
.       ..      .git        .gitignore  Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml  rust-toolchain  src     target
```

If I run

```
rustup override set nightly
```

then the project builds ok, but the default is still "stable".

Answer (score 4):

I'm having a similar issue.

```
$ cat rust-toolchain.toml
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly"
$ rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/n8henrie/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.50.0 (cb75ad5db 2021-02-10)
```

Interestingly, if I remove the `.toml` extension, it works:

```
$ mv rust-toolchain{.toml,}
$ rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/n8henrie/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by '/path/to/cwd/rust-toolchain')
rustc 1.52.0-nightly (3a5d45f68 2021-03-09)
```

It certainly looks like the toml extension should be fine, not sure why it doesn't work:

> In these cases the toolchain can be named in the project's directory in a file called rust-toolchain.toml or rust-toolchain.

https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html?#the-toolchain-file

It also works for me with just the word `nightly`, so I'm not sure why it's not working for you, but it seems like there might be a few quirks here.

Perhaps you could try the `TOML` syntax with file named `rust-toolchain`?

EDIT: Looks like the `.toml` extension is a [recent development](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/pull/2653), perhaps the updates to the book were released before the updates to the tool.

EDIT2: Most recent rustup release is 1.23.1 from 20201202, which is what I'm running, so my issue probably lies here. What version of rustup are you running?

https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/releases

Comment: Removing the `.toml` extension worked for me. I should update rustup soon.

Answer (score 3):

`rustup default` prints the global default toolchain. You can run `rustup show` to get the active toolchain for the current directory:

```sh
$ rustup show

installed toolchains
--------------------
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------
rustc 1.48.0 (7eac88abb 2020-11-16)
```

Setting a directory override will modify the active toolchain:

```
$ rustup override set nightly
$ rustup show

installed toolchains
--------------------
stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (directory override for '/currentproject')
rustc 1.50.0-nightly (e792288df 2020-12-05)
```

Notice how stable is still the *default* toolchain, but the *active* toolchain changed to nightly. To change the global default, you can run the `default` command:

```sh
$ rustup default nightly
$ rustup default
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
```

Comment: Thanks to [Ibraheem Ahmed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8858995/ibraheem-ahmed) for pointing out that `rustup show` provides information about active vs default builds. However, I would like to use the rustup-toolchain file to specify the build so that the correct build will be used if I share my repo. Any ideas of how to get rustup to see the rustup-toolchain file?

Comment: @fox-daniel rustup *will* see the rust-toolchain file and use it as the active toolchain. See [rustup overrides](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html) for more information.

Comment: I understand that it should see the rustup-toolchain file, but I don't think it is. I have created a rustup-toolchain file with only "nightly" in it (no quotes used in the file) and then I run `rustup show`. It shows that stable is the default and active version. Again, I understand that I can use an override command, but I want a solution that allows clones of the repo to have the nightly as the default and active without the other used needing to specify the override.


It seems it is not using nightly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on macOS, make sure rust as installed by Homebrew is not being used, by running the following:

```bash
which cargo
```

If it outputs something like `/opt/homebrew/bin/cargo`, try uninstalling Homebrew rust (`brew uninstall rust`), then run `which cargo` again - it should output something like `/Users/jameshiew/.cargo/bin/cargo`, and `cargo --version` should output the version according to your `rust-toolchain.toml`.

Answer (score 0):

The `rustup show` command is super helpful for identifying the problem. For me the issue was that my global settings in `~/.rustup/settings.toml` were overriding the project settings.
Running `rustup override unset` fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

Do a `rustup update` and this should work.