# rust-toolchain.toml change from msvc to gnu does not work

Tags: rust, toolchain, rustup

I would like to set up a toolchain override for one of my rust projects to use the GNU toolchain instead of the default MSVC one. But somehow the configuration in `rust-toolchain.toml` is ignored. (I am up to date it is not because of the extension.)

Here is how it goes:

```
λ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
rustup home:  C:\Users\<username>\scoop\persist\rustup\.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)
rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
```

As you can see I have the GNU toolchain installed.

So I created the following `rust-toolchain.toml` file:

```
λ cat rust-toolchain.toml
[toolchain]
channel = "stable"
targets = ["x86_64-pc-windows-gnu"]
```

Now when I run `rustup show` I get a result showing the tool is seeing the file, but it does not seem to be processing it correctly since it still wants to use msvc.

```
λ rustup show
Default host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
rustup home:  C:\Users\<username>\scoop\persist\rustup\.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

x86_64-pc-windows-gnu
x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (overridden by 'C:\<project path>\rust-toolchain.toml')
rustc 1.57.0 (f1edd0429 2021-11-29)
```

My guess is that for some reason `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` is considered a valid target for the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` toolchain, but I do not understand why, how to prevent it, or how to write in the `rust-toolchain.toml` file that I want to to use the `x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` target of the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` toolchain and not the one of the `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` toolchain.

How do you think I could solve this?

*Note: using `rustup default stable-gnu` works as expected but I would like to be able to commit something in the repository so that other contributors (and their tools) know they need to use this specific toolchain.*

Edit: rustup version just in case.

```
λ rustup -V
rustup 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)
```

Comment: This question looks eerily similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66603312/3551604

Comment: Yes but changing the extension does nothing for me: `stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc (overridden by 'C:\<project path>\rust-toolchain')`

Answer (score 1):

The target being built for only changes what sys crate will be used for building the binaries against and it's more than possible to cross compile between -msvc and -gnu toolchains in both directions. The problem you're facing here is that your install prefers the msvc toolchain for building.

You can set [directory overrides](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#directory-overrides) with Rustup to force set it; you'll want to run `rustup override set stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu` to force the toolchain change.