# Set a project to use nightly by default

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How do I set a Cargo project to build & run using nightly by default (i.e. `cargo build` is actually `cargo +nightly build`) without setting nightly as the global default?

---

This is not the same question as [How to switch between Rust toolchains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58226545/how-to-switch-between-rust-toolchains). If you read both questions you'll see that question is asking about switching Rust toolchains globally whereas I want to switch Rust toolchains *without* changing the global setting.

Comment: The proposed duplicate target is not specific to setting a Rust toolchain globally. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65644807) proposes `rustup override set`, like in the answer below. And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64701936) shows that it's better to add a `rust-toolchain` file to the project.

Comment: "The proposed duplicate target is not specific to setting a Rust toolchain globally." It doesn't specify, so that means globally. "How do I change my desktop background?" and "How do I change my desktop background on one screen only?" are not the same question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

With `rustup override set nightly` it sets the default for that directory to nightly:

https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#directory-overrides

Answer (score 55):

If you want this choice to also be reflected in the repository, as opposed to just local configuration, you can add a [rust-toolchain.toml](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html#the-toolchain-file) file, for example

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly"
```

You might also want to set the nightly compiler's version (printed by `rustup show`) in the [`rust-version`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-rust-version-field) field of your cargo.toml, so that dependents which try to build on stable get an error message (since rust-toolchain.toml sets the version for a directory, not a crate).