# Corrosion in Eclipse IDE - setting for "Working directory"?

Tags: eclipse, rust, configuration, windows-10

This is on W10...

The Eclipse IDE is the "general" ("C++") version, not the Rust-specific flavoured IDE. Because I'm mainly using other languages: Python, JS, etc.

I'm able to get the format highlighting for my .rs files (following this previous question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177922/595305)).

But I'm completely in the dark about what you're meant to put for Window --> Prefs --> Rust --> "Working directory". This was preset to C:\Desktop, which seemed a bit strange. Whatever I put there seems to raise a "mild" complaint about a missing .toml file.

Surely a .toml file is going to be specific to a given project, rather than generic to the Rust installation itself?

I'm currently mainly running things from the command line rather than from inside Eclipse but I expect that to get the maximum out of Corrosion it's probably best to understand how to configure it properly.

Comment: In Rust/Cargo, the path to the "manifest" file (`Cargo.toml`) is not necessarily the same as the current working directory. I don't know how Corrosion works, so I can't write an answer telling you how to configure that properly, but maybe looking for "manifest" settings would help?